# Geometry Shader : points + Triangles

Tags: c++, directx11

I have different Shaders and for each Shader a instance of the `ShaderClass` class, which initializes the Shaders, Renders the Shaders, etc.

I use most of the `Shaderclass`es without Geometry Shader, but in one Shader Class i also use a Geometry Shader.

The problem is, that when I render one object with the `Shaderclass` that uses the Geometry shader, all other object are rendered with the same geometry that I create in the Geometry Shader.  Can you help me?

Is it possible that I have to use a Geometry Shader for each object, when I use one for one object?

I use DirectX 11 with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the geometry shader, you'll need to do `GSSetShader(NULL, NULL, 0)` to disable it.  Otherwise the geometry shader will remain active during all rendering afterward.

If you use DX11 tessellation shaders (hull & domain shaders) you'll similarly need to set them to NULL when you don't want tessellation anymore.